# Trouble compiling libapreq2

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, compiling, perl

Our app is a monolithic perl app that currently runs on RHEL 6 and I'm trying to get it built on RHEL 7. We run with perlbrew on Perl 5.18.2 threaded. It is installed into our /opt/prism dir but is symlinked to /usr/local/bin/perl so if you see it linked there that's why.  I've gotten most everything setup properly but when I'm attempting to compile libapreq2 I am getting weird issues.

configure runs properly & the make runs without issues. However, make test throws an error about Apache::TestSSLCA

Below are the commands I'm running as a non-root user but first here's perl version info

```
bash# perl -v

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)
```

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/prism/work --enable-perl-glue --with-apache2-apxs=/opt/prism/work/bin/apxs --with-perl=/usr/local/bin/perl
make
make test
```

I get this error:

```
ulimit -c unlimited; /opt/prism/perl5/perlbrew/perls/threaded-perl-5.18.2/bin/perl /opt/PEC.longshot/libapreq2-2.13/module/t/TEST
[  debug] configuring httpd
[  debug] Using httpd: /opt/prism/work/bin/httpd
[  debug] isolated httpd_info VERSION = Apache/2.2.27 (Unix)
[  debug] isolated httpd_info BUILT = May  7 2020 10:37:33
[  debug] isolated httpd_info MODULE_MAGIC_NUMBER = 20051115:33
[  debug] isolated httpd_info SERVER_MPM = Prefork
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines APACHE_MPM_DIR = server/mpm/prefork
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines APR_HAS_SENDFILE = 1
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines APR_HAS_MMAP = 1
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled) = 1
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE = 1
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE = 1
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT = 1
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD = 1
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS = 1
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT = 128
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines HTTPD_ROOT = /opt/prism/work
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines SUEXEC_BIN = /opt/prism/work/bin/suexec
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines DEFAULT_PIDLOG = logs/httpd.pid
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD = logs/apache_runtime_status
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines DEFAULT_LOCKFILE = logs/accept.lock
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines DEFAULT_ERRORLOG = logs/error_log
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE = conf/mime.types
[  debug] isolated httpd_defines SERVER_CONFIG_FILE = conf/httpd.conf
[  debug] inheriting config file: /opt/prism/work/conf/httpd.conf
[  debug] using httpd.conf inherited ServerRoot to resolve conf/mime.types
[  debug] conf/mime.types successfully resolved to existing file /opt/prism/work/conf/mime.types
[  debug] Matched Apache revision Apache/2.2.27 2
[  error] configure() has failed:
Use of each() on hash after insertion without resetting hash iterator results in undefined behavior, Perl interpreter: 0x18a2010 at /opt/prism/perl5/perlbrew/perls/threaded-perl-5.18.2/lib/site_perl/5.18.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Apache/TestSSLCA.pm line 103.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/prism/perl5/perlbrew/perls/threaded-perl-5.18.2/lib/site_perl/5.18.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Apache/TestConfig.pm line 1474.
```

If I look at TestSSLCA.pm line 103 it has

```
#generate DSA versions of the server certs/keys
while (my($key, $val) = each %$cert_dn) {
    next unless $key =~ /^server/;
    my $name = join '_', $key, 'dsa';
    $cert_dn->{$name} = { %$val }; #copy
    $cert_dn->{$name}->{OU} =~ s/rsa/dsa/;
}
```

TestConfig.pm line 1474 just has

```
require Apache::TestSSLCA;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The code you quoted appears to write to `%cert_dn` in the loop which iterates over `%cert_dn`. The version of Perl you are using to compile tells you this isn't allowed.

On RHEL 6 were you building with an older Perl?

I suspect if you upgrade mod_perl or downgrade Perl you'll be able to build successfully.

In the [current mod_perl trunk](http://perl.apache.org/download/source.html#Stable_mod_perl_2_0_Source_Distribution) the fragment in question looks like this:

```
#generate DSA versions of the server certs/keys
for my $key (keys %$cert_dn) {
    next unless $key =~ /^server/;
    my $val = $$cert_dn{$key};
    my $name = join '_', $key, 'dsa';
    $cert_dn->{$name} = { %$val }; #copy
    $cert_dn->{$name}->{OU} =~ s/rsa/dsa/;
}
```

If you copy this into your version of mod_perl the result may build as well.